# I'm trying to convert tradingview script to python. Does anyone know the meaning of [ ] operator?

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert tradingview script code to python, but I have this operator I don't understand and I'd like to get some help with it.

https://www.tradingview.com/script/Q0eQz7ll-Fisher-Transform-Indicator-by-Ehlers-Strategy/

```
Length = input(10, minval=1)
xHL2 = hl2
xMaxH = highest(xHL2, Length)
xMinL = lowest(xHL2,Length)
nValue1 = 0.33 * 2 * ((xHL2 - xMinL) / (xMaxH - xMinL) - 0.5) + 0.67 * nz(nValue1[1])
nValue2 = iff(nValue1 > .99,  .999,
        iff(nValue1 < -.99, -.999, nValue1))
nFish = 0.5 * log((1 + nValue2) / (1 - nValue2)) + 0.5 * nz(nFish[1])
pos =   iff(nFish > nz(nFish[1]), 1,
        iff(nFish < nz(nFish[1]), -1, nz(pos[1], 0))) 
barcolor(pos == -1 ? red: pos == 1 ? green : blue )
plot(nFish, color=green, title="Fisher")
plot(nz(nFish[1]), color=red, title="Trigger")
```

The expression I don't understand is from (nFish[1]) and (nValue1[1]) parts.

In the manual of the script(https://www.tradingview.com/study-script-reference/#op_[]), it says that it's series subscript and provides access to previous values of series.

I tried to convert the script code to python with a dataframe that looks like the below, but I have no idea how to translate (nFish[1]) and (nValue1[1]) parts.

```
                      Date   Open   High    Low  Close
37821  2016/10/13 18:10:00  50.31  50.31  50.27  50.28
37822  2016/10/13 18:09:00  50.30  50.31  50.29  50.31
37823  2016/10/13 18:08:00  50.31  50.31  50.30  50.31
37824  2016/10/13 18:07:00  50.34  50.34  50.31  50.32
37825  2016/10/13 18:06:00  50.37  50.37  50.35  50.35
37826  2016/10/13 18:05:00  50.35  50.37  50.34  50.37
37827  2016/10/13 18:04:00  50.39  50.39  50.35  50.35


for x in range(len(df)):
    Pt = (df.iloc[x,2] + df.iloc[x,3]) / 2.0
    MaxH = df.iloc[x:x+9, 2].max()             
    MinL = df.iloc[x:x+9, 3].min()          

    X = 0.33 * 2.0 * ((Pt - MinL)/(MaxH - MinL) - 0.5) * 0.67 * X[1]  # ?????
```

I'd like to know the meaning of the square brackets in the first script, and if it's possible, I'd like to know how to convert it to Python.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a variable such as `x = []` that means the variable is set as a list or an array whichever you prefer to call it(it's called a list in Python technically) so you can store values in it such as `x = [1,2,3]`.

You can then retrieve these values later in your program by doing `x[0]` where 0 is 1st item in the list.

Edit: So in this case, `x[0]` would be equal to 1 as that is the 1st item in the list.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Then, I need to store X values of each row first? What confuses me is that the X value of each row is dependent on the X value of the previous row..

Comment: I am not familiar with the algorithm you are converting however what I would do is create a list called "values" for example(values = [ ]) and then in your code where you did X = ... after that line do values.append(X) this will store X in the values list so you can later access it by doing values[0].

Comment: Is that helpful? Haha.

Answer (score 2):

in Pine Script on Tradingview, a variable like nFish[1] is the value of the variable nFish 1 bar ago on the chart. nFish[8] is the value of nFish 8 bars ago. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to replicate the fisher transform of TradingView in python.

After looking into multiple codes out there, I found that they implement fisher transform differently. I am still trying to find out:

1- What is MaxH and MinL?

In some documentation it is the highest of all HIGHs in a certain period.Ref: https://wizardforcel.gitbooks.io/python-quant-uqer/content/131.html
In other implementations like yours it is highest of the price which is (high+low)/2 in a certain period. Ref: https://www.mesasoftware.com/papers/UsingTheFisherTransform.pdf
2- Which price does tradingview use to calculate fisher transform, some implementations use the price of (high + low)/2 and some others use the close/open price. 3- The ratio of multiplications, some use (0.33 & 0.67) where others use (0.5 & 0.5).

Here is the python script that I put together to use the highest high and lowest low but it is not matching TradingView's fisher 9 indicator. I tried using the highest/lowest of the price hl with no luck as well.

```
def fisherT(high,low,n):
    high = np.asarray(high,dtype=np.float32)
    low = np.asarray(low,dtype=np.float32)
    sizeArray = len(high)
    hl = (high + low)/2
    maxHln = [max(high[x:x+n]) for x in range(sizeArray-n+1)]
    minHln = [min(low[x:x+n]) for x in range(sizeArray-n+1)]
    valTn = [0.33*2*((hl[x+n-1]-minHln[x])/(maxHln[x]-minHln[x])-0.5) if maxHln[x]-minHln[x] != 0 else 0.33*2*((hl[x+n-1]-minHln[x])/(0.001)-0.5) for x in range(sizeArray-n+1)]
    for i in range(1,sizeArray-n+1):
        valTn[i] = valTn[i] + 0.67 * valTn[i-1]
        if valTn[i] > 0.99:
            valTn[i] = 0.999
        elif valTn[i] < -0.99:
            valTn[i] = -0.999
    _fisher = [0.5*np.log((1.0+valTn[x])/(1.0-valTn[x])) for x in range(sizeArray-n+1)]
    _fisherSignal = []
    for i in range(1,sizeArray-n+1):
        _fisher[i] = _fisher[i] + 0.5 * _fisher[i-1]
        _fisherSignal.append(_fisher[i-1])
    fisher = np.zeros(sizeArray)
    fisherSignal = np.zeros(sizeArray)
    fisher[n-1:] = _fisher
    fisherSignal[n:] = _fisherSignal
    return fisher,fisherSignal
```